# bind cdata element to textbox c#

Tags: c#, xml, binding

I am trying to bind a CData element to a text box, in code.
the xml structure is like this:

```
<Music>
<Category>
<Albums>
 <![CDATA[
    <AlbumData>
      <Album>
          <id>A1</id>
          <Artist>artist 1</Artist>
      </Album>
      <Album>
          <id>A2</id>
          <Artist>artist 2</Artist>
      </Album>

    </AlbumData>
  ]]>
   </Albums>

  </Category>

 </Music>
```

How can I bind the *Artist* to a textbox? I want to make it a two-way binding.

Comment: why is you `AlbumData` in a `CData` section?

Comment: Also, are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: I am using WPF and that data just came from a customer, so I have to deal with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the XML that has for some insane reason been embedded into a CDATA section by your customer, you can do the following:

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("music.xml")
XElement albumData = XElement.Parse(xd.Root.Element("Category").Element("Albums").Value);
```

From there you can use the xml in an `XmlDataProvider` and use XPath to get to the artist's name and display it in a `TextBox`.

I think in your case (a desire to have two way access) it will be easier in the long run to create backing class (model and viewmodel) and then create them from the extracted XML. From those, instead of an `XmlDataProvider`, you set the DataContext of the window to the viewmodel.